# Problem with decimal point setting in Windows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, bcp, locales

I am using bcp.exe from a SQL Server 2017 installation on Windows 10 (build 19041). The OS language is English (US) but I use scandinavian settings for date, time, currency and decimal delimiter - the decimal delimiter is a comma (,) not a point (.)

When I do a "bcp out -c" the file is written, as expected, with decimal point as I am not using the -R option. But when I do a "bcp in" on the same file the . is ignored so 1.23 is imported as 123.

If I change the OS setting to decimal point it works fine, so it seems that "bcp out" works as expected (always decimal point) but "bcp in" erroneously takes Windows settings into account.

Anyone else has this experience and possibly knows a fix?

Comment: Possibly related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/79c37bc0-0d12-40f1-9dda-bacddc236af9/bcp-problem-with-greek-regional-settings?forum=sqltools